# Replace columns data by their grouped value

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

Here are the data :

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
 'A' : ['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar','foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'foo','foo','bar','bar','foo','bar'],
 'B' : ['one', 'one', 'two', 'two','two', 'two', 'one', 'two','one','two','one','two','two'],
 '2018-09-28' : np.random.randn(13), 
 '2018-10-06' : np.random.randn(13),
 '2018-10-13' : np.random.randn(13)
            })

df.index = ['se0','se1','se2','se3','se4','se5','se6','se7',"se8",'se9','se10','se11','se12']
df.index.name = 'SE'
```

In order to replace the all the values by the 'B' group value sum I try this :

```
df_new=df.iloc[:,1:].apply(lambda x : x.groupby('B').sum())
```

But it failed obviously. May you help me ?

Comment: Are you looking for `df.iloc[:, 1:].groupby('B').transform('sum')`

Comment: The same dataframe structure but with the sum grouped by 'B' in place of the current data

Comment: Can you share the sample output what you are expecting.

Comment: if you do  df.groupby('B').sum() you will find 2 numbers ('one' and 'two') by columns. I want these data to replace the current df data

Comment: @mel you can keep repeating the same thing, but it's obvious there is some confusion.  Why don't you put the desired output as a DataFrame in your question.

Comment: will do it next time - thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to check with `transform`

```
df.drop('A',1).groupby('B').transform('sum')
Out[121]: 
      2018-09-28  2018-10-06  2018-10-13
SE                                      
se0     0.766577   -2.250729    1.056958
se1     0.766577   -2.250729    1.056958
se2     2.050151   -1.908386   -1.318890
se3     2.050151   -1.908386   -1.318890
se4     2.050151   -1.908386   -1.318890
se5     2.050151   -1.908386   -1.318890
se6     0.766577   -2.250729    1.056958
se7     2.050151   -1.908386   -1.318890
se8     0.766577   -2.250729    1.056958
se9     2.050151   -1.908386   -1.318890
se10    0.766577   -2.250729    1.056958
se11    2.050151   -1.908386   -1.318890
se12    2.050151   -1.908386   -1.318890
```